# Cis Graphs (Finding Values)

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

For this question:

> [image]

If you guys are not familiar with the $\operatorname{cis}$ notation

$$ \operatorname{cis}(x) = (\cos(x) + i\sin(x)) $$

I've tried doing this:

By comparing arguments

$$ x^2 - x = 0\Longrightarrow x(x-1) = 0\Longrightarrow x = 0 ,~ x = 1 $$
But clearly from the graph there are more intersections and searching the internet I learnt you can do this

$$ x^2  = x + 2k\pi $$

But why can we plus $2k\pi$ and does the $2k\pi$ have to be on the right side of the equation why can't it be on the left hand side?

Comment: Rather expand and compare real and imaginary parts

Comment: The key idea is that $\operatorname{cis}x=\operatorname{cis}y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ differ by an integer multiple of $2\pi$. Try proving that. (And yes, $2k\pi$ can be on either side of your equation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\text{cis}\left(x^2\right)=\text{cis}(x)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\cos\left(x^2\right)+\sin\left(x^2\right)i=\cos(x)+\sin(x)i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{ix^2}=e^{ix}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln\left(e^{ix^2}\right)=\ln\left(e^{ix}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$ix^2=ix\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2=x\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Notice, if $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

$a+bi=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{\arg(a+bi)i}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{\left(2\pi k+\arg(a+bi)\right)i}$

---

$$x^2-x+2\pi k=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use the abc-formula:

---

$$x=\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-8\pi k}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{with}\space k\in\mathbb{Z}$$